# Reload page after CRUD

Tags: javascript, angular, api

I'm looking for a way to reload the page after a CRUD operation who was transparent for user.

Actually after a create or delete, I have to reload the page to show my operations.

I use a api to make this, when I use it with json file, it work fine.

Thanks

Example for delete:

```
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
  displayedColumns = ['first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'mail', 'role', 'action'];
  action: any;
  selectedUser: User;
  @Input() user: User;
  data: any;


  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private userService: UserService, public dialog: MatDialog) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

    this.userService.getUsers()
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this.dataSource.data = response;
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log('error ' + error);
        }
      );
  }

  onDelete(selectedUser){
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
      type: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {
        this.userService.delete(selectedUser.id).subscribe(res => {
          this.dataSource.data.splice(selectedUser.id, 1);
        });
        Swal.fire(
          'Deleted!',
          'User has been deleted.',
          'success'
        )
      }
    })
  }
```

the html code

let me know if you want more code , and what part of code.

```
  <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort multiTemplateDataRows >

      <!-- First name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="first_name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> First name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.first_name}} </td>
        <label>
          <input class="table-input" *ngIf="selectedUser" type="text">
        </label>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Middle name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="middle_name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Middle name </th>
        <td mat-cell class="status" *matCellDef="let element">{{element.middle_name}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Last name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="last_name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Last name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.last_name}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Email Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="mail">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Email </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.mail}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Role Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="role">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Role </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{getRole(element)}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Actions Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Actions </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="editUserBtn" (click)="openEditDialog(row)"><mat-icon class="edit-icon" >launch</mat-icon><span>Edit</span></button>
          <button mat-raised-button color="warn" class="deleteUserBtn" (click)="onDelete(row)"><mat-icon class="delete-icon" >delete_outline</mat-icon><span>Delete</span></button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
    <mat-paginator [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 15]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far. Paste some code.

Comment: update delete method

Comment: Can you show us the template as well? How are you binding the data to the template?

Comment: Be more specific, please. Could You show more code?

Comment: post updated, let me know if you want something else

Comment: Instead of mutating the data in subscribe, what if you instead return a new array with that one item omitted?

Comment: Why would you have to reload the page? That does not make sense and is probably not what you want. Re-loading the page means loading everything from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use `BehaviorSubject` in this case. `BehaviorSubject` keeps listening to the subscriber and updates whenever there is a `next` emit.

```
dataSource: BehaviorSubject<MatTableDataSource[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

onDelete(selectedUser) {
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
  }).then(result => {
    if (result.value) {
      this.userService.delete(selectedUser.id).subscribe(res => {
        this.dataSource.value.data.splice(selectedUser.id, 1);
        this.dataSource.next(this.dataSource.value);
      });
      Swal.fire('Deleted!', 'User has been deleted.', 'success');
    }
  });
}
```

where MatTableDataSource should be your data type.

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the material data Table, the easiest way is to refresh the whole datasource:

```
 dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
  displayedColumns = ['first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'mail', 'role', 'action'];
  action: any;
  selectedUser: User;
  @Input() user: User;
  data: any;


  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private userService: UserService, public dialog: MatDialog) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadDataTable();
  }

  loadDataTable() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

    this.userService.getUsers()
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this.dataSource.data = response;
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log('error ' + error);
        }
      );
  }

  onDelete(selectedUser){
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
      type: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {
        this.userService.delete(selectedUser.id).subscribe(res => {
          this.loadDataTable();
          Swal.fire(
            'Deleted!',
            'User has been deleted.',
            'success'
          );
        },
        // Probably you want to add some error handling here:
        (error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
      }
    })
```

Comment: I did it but nothing change

Comment: No it's the same thing happen, the data is update but I need to reload the page to see the change, I want to update data, and update the table without have to reload the page , I want a seamless thing.

Comment: Then you have to relaod the whole datasource. You can't just splice the data... See my updated answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Pipe *delete call* with the *get call*.

```
      deleteUser(){ // called on click of delete
         this.userSvc
          .deleteUser() // service function that deletes a user. Could be any of CUD (Create, Update or Delete
          .pipe(   
            switchMap(data => this.userSvc.getUsers()) // pipe the result and perform retrieve.
           )
        .subscribe( result => this.users = result); // finally set the result on a field to show on the component template.    
    }
```

Here is a quick sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-agpxba?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

There are other approaches to achieve the same, especially if we use Application State Management frameworks like ngrx. We may identify state changed and trigger retrieve API. The one here is simplistic. Sample is coded fairly quickly in 15 minutes.

Comment: I'll test your code tomorrow, do you do the same for the create method, because I have the same problem than delete method.

Comment: Use the link (in the answer above). It's a working sample.
The same can be done for "create" as well.

Comment: what's the if statement for status 500 or 200 in user.service ?

Comment: I just test your method and it's doesn't work for me , the delete is okay but I need to refresh the page to see it on the table ... I'm lost...

Comment: A typical single page app does not refresh the page. Update the component with new data. Anyways, all the best.

Comment: But it's weird because it works with hard code data and not api.